# artisan command can't take argument Laravel

Tags: laravel, command-line, laravel-artisan

I have developed a package for laravel 5, I also have created a command for this package, the command file is like this:

```
 class MyCommand extends Command {

    protected $name = 'package:command';

   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
    }

  public function fire()
 {
    $this->info('');$this->info('');$this->info('');

    $this->info('            [ Package ]       ');
    $this->info('               ------------------');
    $this->call(\\some codes here ... );
 }

 protected function getArguments()
 {
    return [];
  }
```

And this is how I register the command in ServiceProvider

```
    $this->app['package:command'] = $this->app->share(function()
    {
        return new \MyNameSpace\Package\MyCommand();
    });
```

The command `package:command` works fine, but as soon as I try to run it with an argument the following error will come 
`Too many argumnents`,

Question:
where in my code should be modified so that I can pass the argument to the command?
 **edited:** and how to get this argument in the `fire()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put them in the `getArguments()` method that currently returns an empty array. See documentation here: [for 5.0](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/commands), or [for 4.2](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands).

So, for instance:

```
protected function getArguments()
{
    return [
        ['example', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'required argument example'],
        ['example2', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'optional argument example', 'some default value']
    ];
}
```

Comment: so if I add the below lines to the `getArguments()` function how do I have to run the command in the command-line, for example:
`php artisan package:command arg1`

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. You just type the arguments after the command.

Comment: I just edited the question, please check it,  wonder how to take this argument in the `fire()` method?

Comment: You have to put it in the `getArguments()` method as I showed, otherwise you can't retrieve it in `fire()`. After you have done that, you can retrieve the argument in `fire()` by e.g. `$exampleValue = $this->argument('example');`